# Unable to load assembly in strongly signed silverlight code

Tags: silverlight, reflection, silverlight-4.0

In a Silverlight 4 app I'm trying to instantiate an object whose type isn't known until run-time, using this code:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Name.Of.Some.dll");
Type type = assembly.GetType("Full.NameSpace.And.ClassName");
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

However, the Assembly.LoadFrom() call results in an exception:

```
{System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'Mosaic.Layers.LayerParamChangeHandlerInfo.CreateParamHandler()' to access security critical method 'System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(System.String)' failed.
```

I've done some Googling for the error, but I still can't figure out why I'm getting the exception (something related to the assemblies being strongly signed, I believe) and, more importantly, how to solve the problem and create my object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to call this method from your own code, cause its security critical and restricted to be used only internal in .NET Framework.

> Do not use this member in your application. If you do, your code will throw a MethodAccessException. This member is security-critical, which restricts it to internal use by the .NET Framework for Silverlight class library.

The only available Load method for assemblies in Silverlight is [Assembly.Load(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). If you want to dynamically load an assemblies, take a look at [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/14941.aspx) approach.

Comment: Looking at the docs for Assembly.LoadString(), the required parameter is the full assembly name, but it's not clear exactly what that is in my case. I tried both "Name.Of.Some.dll" and "Name.Of.Some", which both result in a FileNotFoundException.

And, unless I misread it, the article you linked is using a Stream to load from - I don't have  a Stream - just the name of the assembly & class that I need to instantiate.

Comment: @Dave W: Where is the assembly located, that you are trying to load? Do you run your silverlight application in Out-Of-Browser?

Comment: @Dave W: I think you need to specify the full assembly name including version, culture and public key token. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015513/silverlight-assembly-load-only-works-with-the-full-strong-name

Comment: (Forgive me if my answers are somewhat vague - I'm not very familiar with Silverlight but have been asked to add a feature to an existing app, so I'm not really clear on all the Silverlight-specific stuff) - the app is loaded in browser as part of a web page.

Comment: So how do I know what the full name is, especially that public key part? I have a solution with a number of projects in - will that information be somewhere in the project for the assembly I'm trying to load?

Comment: I don´t know a built in way in Visual Studio to get the full name of an assembly. I´ve installed the extension VSCommands 2010 and with this you can right click on a referenced assembly to "Show Assembly Details". The Details include the FullName of the assembly containing all relevant values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4135/discussion-between-jehof-and-dave-w)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have now resolved the issue.  I used a program called ".Net Reflector" to help me find the full assembly name, then used:
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Name.Of.Some, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4c234103aed70fc");
            Type type = assembly.GetType("Full.NameSpace.And.ClassName");
            object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type)